# Pivoting a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Sample data from a SQL Server table is shown below:

```
+------------+---------+---------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
|    Date    | Account |  Head   | D_C | TxnID | AmCode | Amount |
+------------+---------+---------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 15-05-2019 |     123 | Savings | D   |     5 | SV     |    150 |
| 15-05-2019 |     123 | Cash    | C   |     5 | SV     |    150 |
| 16-05-2019 |     367 | Loan    | D   |     6 | LN     |    200 |
| 16-05-2019 |     367 | Cash    | C   |     6 | LN     |    200 |
+------------+---------+---------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
```

There are two pairs (4 rows) shown above. All the fields in each pair are the same (even when the data is unsorted - although it is sorted above) except for the `Head` and `D_C Column` which are different for the pair.

I am looking for a report as below from the above sample:

```
+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
|    Date    | Account | D Head  | C Head | TxnID | AmCode | Amount |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| 15-05-2019 |     123 | Savings | Cash   |     5 | SV     |    150 |
| 16-05-2019 |     367 | Loan    | Cash   |     6 | LN     |    200 |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

That is one row in the report for the pair with the Head + D combination in one column and Head + C combination in another.

Please note that in the actual data the pairs may not appear together as above. However, the concatenation of fields other than Head + D_C makes the concatenated string unique for a pair of rows.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to merge debit and credit pairs which have the same:

- `Date`
- `Account`
- `TxnID`
- `AmCode`
- `Amount`

While still retaining both `Head` descriptions for the debits and credits.

```
;with Debit --Define Debit CTEas only debit lines
as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM datatable
    WHERE D_C='D'
),
Credit  --Define Credit CTE as only debit lines
as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM datatable
    WHERE D_C='C'
)
SELECT DISTINCT --Get only unique lines
    d.[Date],
    d.[Account],
    d.Head as [D Head],
    c.Head as [C Head],
    d.TxnID,
    d.AmCode,
    d.Amount
From [Debit] d
INNER JOIN --Join on all the same fields
    [Credit] c
ON 
    d.Date = c.Date
AND 
    d.Account = c.Account
AND 
    d.TxnID = c.TxnID
AND 
    d.AMCode = c.AmCode
AND 
    c.Amount = d.Amount
```

This code above is based on the fact that you will only ever have one debit and one credit line per pair. If this is not the case, the code will need to be modified.

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Your understanding is right. From the answer, looks the solution is also right. Sadly, the SQL Server in my Laptop is not responding for me to test and confirm the solution. Will need to wait till Monday for the IT Team to fix the issue. Going by my intuition, I am marking the answer as correct. Will revert/confirm on Monday. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try with conditional aggregation:

```
declare @tmp table
(
     [Date]  date,  
     Account int,   
     Head    varchar(50),  
     D_C     char(1),  
     TxnID   int,  
     AmCode  char(2),  
     Amount  int
)

insert into @tmp
values
 ('2019-05-15', 123, 'Savings', 'D', 5, 'SV', 150) 
,('2019-05-15', 123, 'Cash'   , 'C', 5, 'SV', 150) 
,('2019-05-16', 367, 'Loan'   , 'D', 6, 'LN', 200) 
,('2019-05-16', 367, 'Cash'   , 'C', 6, 'LN', 200) 

select  
  [Date]
, Account
, max(case when D_C='D' then Head end )as [D Head]
, max(case when D_C='C' then Head end )as [C Head]
, TxnID
, AmCode
, Amount 
From @tmp
group by [Date], Account, TxnID, AmCode, Amount
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrea.  Solution looks much simpler. Will test on Monday (when, hopefully, the SSMS in my machine starts working) and revert.